# How to set different <a href> and <img src> dynamically in divs with same class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array of objects(each that are made up of image link and link). As I access each of them I would like to make a new div each time and add a different image link and link.

```
<div class="igo_product"
    <a href>
        link1
        <img class="igo_product_image" src="imglink1">
</div>
<div class="igo_product"
    <a href>
        link2
        <img class="igo_product_image" src="imglink2">
</div>
<div class="igo_product"
    <a href>
        link3
        <img class="igo_product_image" src="imglink3">
</div>
```

Currently the only way I can place different images and links is by creating different class names by concatenating indexes at the end each time.

```
$.each(items, function (index, value) {
    $(".igo_boxbody").append('<div class="igo_product' + index + '"<a><img class="igo_product_image' + index + '"></a></div>')
    $(".igo_product" + index + "a").attr('href', value["link"].toString());
    $(".igo_product_image" + index).attr('src', value["image_link"] );
});
```

However, `$(".igo_product" + index + "a").attr('href', value["link"].toString());` does not correctly set my href...I'm assuming it's my way I'm concatenating the class, index, and a but I'm slightly stuck on what else I can do. Also, is there a better way to do this? I would rather keep the class name the same so that I can apply styles to all these classes easier.

Comment: The generated markup is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$.each(items, function (index, value) {
                $(".igo_boxbody").append('<div class="igo_product"<a href="'+value["link"].toString()+'"><img class="igo_product_image" src="'+value["image_link"]+'"></div>');
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error:

```
$(".igo_boxbody").append('<div class="igo_product' + index + '"<a><img class="igo_product_image' + index + '"></a></div>')
 //-----------------------------------------------------------^---no closing of div >
```

so change to this:

```
$(".igo_boxbody").append('<div class="igo_product' + index + '"><a><img class="igo_product_image' + index + '"></a></div>')
```

---

Should go for this:

```
$.each(items, function (index, value) {
    var el = '<div class="igo_product"' + index 
             + '><a href="'+value["link"]
             +'"><img class="igo_product_image' + index 
             + '" src="'+value["image_link"]+'"></a></div>'
    $(".igo_boxbody").append(el);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By no means I intend to imply the following is better, but just to mention the option: you can use jquery to create html objects outside the DOM (e.g. `$('<div>')` creates a new div) and set their properties/attributes/classes/etc through those objects (also before adding them to the DOM).
The advantage is that you don't have to delve into the strings to catch those closing tags:

```
$('.igo_boxbody').append(items.map(function(value, index){
    return  $('<div>').addClass('igo_product').append(
        $('<a>').attr('href', value.link).append(
          $('<img>').attr('src', value.image_link).addClass('igo_product_image' + index)
     )
  );
}));
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k9c8bm04)